# Container credentials access denied exception

Tags: amazon-ec2, containers

I am a newbie trying to get a Docker image into an `AWS container` registry. According to the [`AWS documentation`](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-east-1#/repositories/create), I enter credentials into the `AWS CLI` and then issue the command `aws ecr get-login`.

This results in the following:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: 
User: arn:aws:iam::847077264418:user/xxx 
is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
```

Clearly this is something in the `AWS IAM`. How do I fix it?

Comment: I had attached ec2 container access policy previously and this did not work. When I attached administrator, it did. Since this is for a class, the overkill does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, IAM users don't have permission to create or modify Amazon
>   ECR resources, or perform tasks using the Amazon ECR API. (This means
>   that they also can't do so using the Amazon ECR console or the AWS
>   CLI.) To allow IAM users to create or modify resources and perform
>   tasks, you must create IAM policies that grant IAM users permission to
>   use the specific resources and API operations they'll need, and then
>   attach those policies to the IAM users or groups that require those
>   permissions.

from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_IAM_policies.html

Comment: I had attached ec2 container access policy previously and this did not work. When I attached administrator, it did. Since this is for a class, the overkill does not matter.